# Get Youtube playlist on bases of Genre in iOS

Tags: swift, youtube

i have searched about getting youtube playlist , but it provides list of songs from our youtube channel, but i'm trying to get youtube songs playlist on bases of genre. For example if user is sad it should return the list of sad songs and so on. It works in spotify fine it returns on bases of genre, but how i can get in youtube?

Comment: I don't think youtube provides genre because it has many categorized content with different content, but you can use categories of youtube.

Comment: any other platform that provide free playlist for genre music? @EndLess

Comment: No, and I just got to know that you can't even use categories too

Comment: ohh okay, so we can only get list of playlist from our own channel only? @EndLess